# Capability analysis of Profile of a line measurement

Tags: distributions, engineering-statistics

Working on Validations of a machining process and trying to understand how to show capability of a machining process that is measured using "profile of a line".
This is measured by a probe measuring how well a profile meets the theoretical line by checking at several intervals and then returns 2 measurements (Max and Min). The Max is the highest value measured vs the imaginary line and the min is the lowest value. Both measurements assume the imaginary line to be at 0. Sometimes the min is a positive value because all measurements were on the positive side.

The trouble I have is that as a max and min measurement won't be a normal distribution (practice proves this) what would we expect? I can use a distribution identifier but that fits the best to the data and won't show me if it is off.
Also is the capability analysis as simple as working on the transform once a distribution is identified?